# Customise WPF "Slider" control to slide on a path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, slider

What would be the best way to get a slider control that slides on a path. At the moment I think the path I will use is a half circle arc. But I may need to change this later (or create other sliders with different paths. So I need to take that into account.

Would it be best to start with the default Slider control and modify/extend it? or is it best to start from scratch? The existing Slider does have some functionality I would like to keep, so it sounds to me like using the existing slider would be best.

I was hoping there was a "Path" property **:)** but that would be asking too much... or would it?

Answer (score 3):

Charles Petzold is your man, this isn't exactly the answer to your question, but it should be a good starting point:
http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/08/Curved-ScrollBars.html

Answer (score 2):

Well, not having expression blend, it seems that the tool XamlPadX allows you to extract the control template of the standard WPF slider. This will give you a good starting point, although admittedly, the output looks daunting. Let us know how you get along!